# How to return an attribute from a cartesian product?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, database-design

So basically the question I have to answer is this:

**"Return the panum of papers written by the academic “Mark Yee”."**

Here is the database I'm using:
https://ufile.io/72wph

The relational schema for the Academics database is as follows:

DEPARTMENT( deptnum , descrip, instname, deptname, state, postcode)

ACADEMIC( acnum , deptnum*, famname, givename, initials, title)

PAPER( panum , title)

AUTHOR( panum*, acnum* )

FIELD( fieldnum , id, title)

INTEREST( fieldnum*, acnum* , descrip)

Some notes on the Academics database:

● An academic department belongs to one institution ( instname ) and often has many academics. An
academic only works for one department.

● Research papers ( PAPER ) are often authored by several academics, and of course an academic often
writes several papers ( AUTHOR ).

● A research field ( FIELD ) often attracts many academics and an academic can have interest
( INTEREST ) in several research fields.

I know I have to join these two tables, but what should I do afterwards?

I've tried(This just lists all the PANUM's):

```
SELECT PANUM
FROM ACADEMIC, AUTHOR   
WHERE FAMNAME LIKE '%Yee%' AND GIVENAME LIKE '%Mark%';
```

Comment: Would really help if you post the table schema with some sample test.

Comment: What is the expected output? Number of PANUM papers?

Comment: I just uploaded the database.

Comment: Why did you need `CROSS JOIN`?

Comment: **STOP using commas between table names!** YOU need to use INNER JOINs and the ACNUM or PANUM is found in more then one table, so it is through those columns that the joins are made.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT PA.PANUM, PA.TITLE
FROM ACADEMIC AC
INNER JOIN AUTHOR AU ON AC.ACNUM = AU.ACNUM
INNER JOIN PAPER PA ON PA.PANUM = AU.PANUM
WHERE AC.FAMNAME = 'Yee' AND AC.GIVENAME = 'Mark';
```

Comment: Your answer was worth an upvote because it's correct.  But it would be much better with an explanation.

Answer (score -1):

The table `author` holds 2 foreign keys `acnun` (for the academic) and `panum` (for the "paper") those columns are also found in other tables. Use those common columns to JOIN tables together in a logical manner.

```
select a.panum, d.famname, d.givename
from AUTHOR a
INNER JOIN ACADEMIC d ON a.acnum = d.acnum
```

*In ancient times when SQL was first used it was common to use `from table1, table2` but this is no longer considered best practice and even if your teachers want you to use that syntax, don't.*

Comment: Yeah my teacher taught us to do it that way, I guess I'll use your way instead.

Comment: Inform your teacher that "ANSI JOINS" was standardized over 25 years ago and it simply is bad practice to use the older less precise syntax. A good thing about using the newer join syntax is it forces you to consider which columns you need to use for the joins which you can forget to do in the older method  (leading to unwanted Cartesian products)

Comment: Opinions are divided on whether comma join is prefereable or not. The comma join syntax is ANSI standard and ISO standard SQL. It is not any more "less precise" than the INNER JOIN syntax and in some cases many people will find it more concise and natural  - especially when some of the tables being joined are not included in the predicates. Another consideration is that there are some subtle differences in the JOIN ... ON clauses allowed in certain DBMSs. Comma join is more standardized and works the same in all DBMSs in my experience.

Comment: Opinion isn't divided equally, these proposing that "comma joins" are good practice are most definitely in a minority here at SO for example and "comma joining" is included in standards simply for support of legacy code.

Comment: comma join is ok. it is the notation that is similar to relational algebra, where there is also no on clause. there are a lot of people shouting here that one has to use inner join syntax but nevertheless this is not true.I think the main difference is that Oracle has a mostly of comma join samples in its documentation but microsoft uses inner join syntax in its  documentation,.

Comment: The older syntax isn't less precise.  It's just harder to read because it conceals intent instead of revealing it.  But I agree that the student should be taught the newer syntax.

Comment: @WalterMitty the difference in precision is in the ordering of the join information. The old join syntax is lax on ordering the joins, which is not true with the explicit syntax where you do have to take care with the joins sequence. Hence there is a real difference in precision (of the syntax).

Comment: AFAIK the Oracle query optimizer has always been able to play with the join order under both the old and the new syntax.  Of course the strategies considered by the optimizer all have to be logically equivalent.

Comment: @WalterMitty the points raised are not about an optimizer, they are about syntax; "comma join syntax" -v- "explicit join syntax". Of course an optimizer is able to amend the actual execution of a query, such as doing the from clause before a where clause, but that isn't relevant to the written syntax.

Comment: The comma join syntax is not "lax" about join ordering because logically speaking there is no join ordering. The joins are associative and commutative. The INNER JOIN ... ON syntax takes SQL further away from the relational algebra concept of joins. I expect the teacher in this case is well aware of both syntax but is trying to educate students about the fundamentals of joins before having to deal with the peculiarities of SQL syntax.

Comment: Another consideration is that the comma syntax is implemented in a consistent way in all DBMSs I know of. The JOIN ... ON syntax has some subtle variations between different implementations.